# Eigen, Matrix resizing issue when implementing damped pseudo inverse

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to implement a damped pseudo inverse function for any sized matrices with Eigen. I don't understand why this implementation is not working.

Function:

```
template<typename Derived>
Derived dampedPinv(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& a, double rho = 1e-4) {
  return a.transpose() * (a*a.transpose() + rho*rho*Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::Identity(a.rows(), a.rows()) ).inverse();
}
```

Function call:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd a = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6,1);
a(3,0) = 1;
Eigen::MatrixXd ainv = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6,1);
ainv = dampedPinv(a);
```

Error message:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/PlainObjectBase.h:258: 
void Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>::resize(Eigen::Index, Eigen::Index) [with Derived = Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, -1>; Eigen::Index = long int]: 
Assertion `(!(RowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows==RowsAtCompileTime)) && 
           (!(ColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (cols==ColsAtCompileTime)) && 
           (!(RowsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxRowsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (rows<=MaxRowsAtCompileTime)) && 
           (!(ColsAtCompileTime==Dynamic && MaxColsAtCompileTime!=Dynamic) || (cols<=MaxColsAtCompileTime)) && 
           rows>=0 && cols>=0 && 
           "Invalid sizes when resizing a matrix or array."' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: How would one go about debugging this?

Comment: Try decomposing the  expression in your function in several steps.
Then run your code in a debugger to see which of these steps triggers the assert. This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Huh. The error says that you try to resize to 6 x -1. Can you tell us which of the function call lines is line 258? Have you tried to type it again, assuming that there is some strange hidden character that somehow makes the 1 negative? By the way, shouldn't ainv be 1x6?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce with this self-contained example:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
Derived dampedPinv(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& a, double rho = 1e-4) {
  return a.transpose() * (a*a.transpose() + rho*rho*Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>::Identity(a.rows(), a.rows()) ).inverse();
}

int main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXd a = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6,1);
  a(3,0) = 1;
  Eigen::MatrixXd ainv = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(6,1);
  ainv = dampedPinv(a);
  std::cout << ainv << "\n";
}
```

using either Eigen 3.2.10 or 3.3.1. Please make sure you are using an up-to-date version, and if so and that you still get the issue, run it in a debugger to get the backtrace and step in to see which precise condition is not met.